# Filter DHCPv6 solicit packets

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux, firewall, iptables

I am trying to filter the dhcpv6 solicit(1) packets using ip6tables rule but the following rule is not working:
`ip6tables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 547 -m u32 --u32 "48@0>>24&0xff=0x1" -j DSCP  --set-dscp 1`

but this rule is not working. It is not tagging the DHCPv6 frames.
In the rule, 48 is 40(Ipv6) + 8(UDP) and since information is present in the first byte of DHCPv6 header, so extracting it.

Please suggest a correction.

Comment: Used the global index starting from the Ip header solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Global index to get the DHCP first byte from the IPv6 header solves the issue.